# @font-face issues with Firefox

Tags: css, web, dns, font-face, webfonts

It may only be an issue with Firefox but whenever visiting the site using www. as a prefix the embedded fonts don't load even when using an absolute path.

I don't know if there are ways to reinforce this using CSS or there is some kind of DNS issues with the www. that I need to edit, but I'm all out of options of how to fix this.

could anyone share some help with this?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Book';
    src: url('fonts/futurastdbook.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/futurastdbook.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/futurastdbook.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/futurastdbook.svg') format('svg');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bold';
    src: url('fonts/FuturaStd-Bold.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/FuturaStd-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/FuturaStd-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/FuturaStd-Bold.svg') format('svg');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Medium';
    src: url('fonts/futurastdmedium.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/futurastdmedium.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/futurastdmedium.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/futurastdmedium.svg') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is a cross-domain issue. From the developer tools web console:

```
[15:16:47.796] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Medium" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://garrettlockhart.com/fonts/futurastdmedium.woff @ http://garrettlockhart.com/style.css
```

One fix would be to set one or the other url as canonical and use that throughout.

Comment: thanks for the help but this goes way over my head haha

could you give me a bit more info how to do that